# PHP undefined index with array of MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a script to rename duplicate names to "$name2" in a user DB in MySQL but for some reason I get the error "Undefined index" for each duplicate username and the "foreach" loop isn't being used. The code is the following:

```
$result = mysql_query("select name, count(*) cnt from users group by name having cnt > 1 and name!=''");
$rowsCnt = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $rows[] = $row;
    $rowsCnt[ $row['name'] ]++;
}

foreach($rows as $index => $row) {
                mysql_query("UPDATE users SET duplicate=1, name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($row['name'])."2' WHERE name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($row['name'])."'"$
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `while` loop and then a `foreach` loop? It doesn't look like you're using `$rowsCnt`

Comment: You don't think the complete error message may have been useful here?

Comment: From the PHP Manual on [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php): This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: Also, your update query is going to update all the found names to `name + '2'`. Probably not what you want to do

Comment: Another one; you need a `WHERE` clause for `name != ''`. You can't tack that on to `HAVING`

Comment: Well the full error is for example:
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Alex in /home/default/usernames.php on line 18

mysql_query seems to be still working~

Thank you Phil I will add a check :)

Comment: (Alex is a username selected from DB in that example)

Answer (score 2):

The undefined index is being thrown because of this line:

```
$rowsCnt[$row['name']]++;
```

The value of $row['name'] is not representing any item in $rowsCnt array, in other words, there is no index in the array $rowCnt with the name $row['name'].

A side note: You might want to rewrite your code cause it could be written in a much better way.